# Integration of react native with existing android apps and adding native modules

Tags: android, react-native, react-hooks

I've existing android native app and converted that app to react native and added native modules in it. but in react native, native module is showing as 'null'.

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following link for android native modules docs to help in making native modules for android, it may be lead to success.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android

Comment: I followed these steps, for normal react native project it is working, but if i convert existing native android project to react native and then adding native module, getting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.
React package was missing in package.json file. installed the react latest version